# How to change the address bar back to tabs from input text in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcuts

After Ctrl+L or click "Enter Location" from the menu, the tab of nautilus becomes input text.

But how can I go back to the tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click in the text box and hit [Esc]